# Grant permission to user to view local computer certificate store

Tags: windows, administration, certificate

Administrators have access to personal certificate store and to local computer certificate store. Common users have access only to personal certificate store. How I can give users access to local computer store without making them administrators?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a Group permission on the cert. store and add users to the group.

Comment: Mm.. I launched mmc.exe and examined `Certificates (Local Computer)` and I haven't found how to set a Group permission. Please, tell me how to it by steps.

Comment: Do you mean: set a Group permission on the cert. store in file system?